# TypeError: Input 'filename' of 'ReadFile' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of string

Tags: python, keras

I am running this code from the tutorial here: https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/

with a custom dataset, that is divided in 2 datasets as in the tutorial. However, I got this error:

```
TypeError: Input 'filename' of 'ReadFile' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of string.
```

I made this casting. I tried this:

```
is_jfif = str(tf.compat.as_bytes("JFIF")) in fobj.peek(10)
```

but nothing changed as far as the error
I am trying all day to figure out how to solve it, without any success. Can someone help me? Thank you...

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: Look at (and post) the whole traceback.  In other words the exact error.  You code line has nothing to do with `filename` or `ReadFile`.

Comment: I think I fixed it, thnx a lot for your time...

Comment: @just_learning how do you fix this problem

Comment: I ran it in colab

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simplest way I found is to create a subfolder and copy the files to that subfolder.
i.e. Lets assume your files are 0.jpg, 1.jpg,2.jpg....2000.jpg and in directory named "patterns".

Seems like the Keras API does not accept it as the files are named by numbers and for Keras it is in float32.

To overcome this issue, either you can rename the files as one answer suggests, or you can simply create a subfolder under "patterns" (i.e. "patterndir"). So now your image files are under ...\patterns\patterndir

Keras (internally) possibly using the subdirectory name and may be attaching it in front of the image file thus making it a string (sth like patterndir_01.jpg, patterndir_02.jpg) [Note this is my interpretation, does not mean that it is true]

When you compile it this time, you will see that it works and you will get a compiler message as:

```
Found 2001 files belonging to 1 classes.
Using 1601 files for training.
Found 2001 files belonging to 1 classes.
Using 400 files for validation.
```

My code looks like this

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

#Generate a dataset

image_size = (28, 28)
batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "patterns",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=1337,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "patterns",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=1337,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
```

Comment: if your batch size is 32 how you gonna load rest of the images please explain !!

Comment: The error is produced even if the files are not named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ...

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I simply did not have enough samples in the training directories. There was one per category and I got the error.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a subdirectory and move your files there.

So if the files are here:

```
'/home/dataset_28/'
```

Put them here:

```
'/home/dataset_28/files/'
```

And then do this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
image_dataset_from_directory('/home/dataset_28/', batch_size=1, image_size=(28, 28))
```

Answer (score 1):

The names of the files are in the float32 format.
Renaming all the images in the dataset solves the problem.
Loop over all the files with `os.rename()`.

Comment: Renaming the files to what? If my files are for example patterns/class1/image1.png etc., to what should I rename them?

Answer (score 1):

I was just hitting this `TypeError: Input 'filename' of 'ReadFile' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of string.` error too with `tensorflow==2.4.4`.

I played around with `validation_split`:

- Error happens: `validation_split=0.001`

  - I did this in an effort to have 0 images in the validation set.
- Error doesn't happen: `validation_split=0.2`

  - This results in 1 image used for validation

Conclusion: a known root cause of this error is 0 images inside the validation set.

---

**Failed Fixes**

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63434999/11163122) I renamed my files via `os.rename` to `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`, ... didn't work :/

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64784344/11163122) talking about one image/category, that's wrong, it's fine to have just one image inside a category.

Answer (score 1):

One of the issues is related to the image downloading. If a designated image document is not downloaded, it also show the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the several things after this exception appeared:

1. Do you have enough data for training?

If you only have limited data in your training set, this exception would appear. I guess if you want to split the data, the amount of the data should be divisible by 10 (Take validation_split=0.1 for example).

2. Do your image in valid format?

This method only allows formats in ('.bmp', '.gif', '.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png'). Invalid format would appear this exception.

Honestly, the exception doesn't give much information of what's happening exactly. Hopefully would update in near future.