# How to create a Tensorflow Dataset without labels? Input 'filename' of 'ReadFile' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of string

Tags: dataset

Using Tensorflow 2.3, I'm trying to create a tf.data.Dataset without labels.
I have my **.png** files in a folder './Folder/'. For creating the minimal working sample, I think the only relevant line is the one where I am calling **tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory**. [The class definition is here.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset.py#L34-L206)

```
    dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory('./Folder/',label_mode=None,batch_size=100)
```

When the Python interpreter reaches the line above, it returns this error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 465, in _apply_op_helper
    values = ops.convert_to_tensor(
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1473, in convert_to_tensor
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype string for Tensor with dtype float32: <tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=() dtype=float32>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "04-vaeAnomalyScores.py", line 135, in <module>
    historicKLD, encoder, decoder, vae = artVAE_Instance.run_autoencoder()  # Train
  File "/media/roi/9b168630-3b62-4215-bb7d-fed9ba179dc7/images/largePatches/artvae.py", line 386, in run_autoencoder
    trainingDataSet = self.loadImages(self.trainingDir)
  File "/media/roi/9b168630-3b62-4215-bb7d-fed9ba179dc7/images/largePatches/artvae.py", line 231, in loadImages
    dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(dir[:-1]+'Downscaled/',label_mode=None,batch_size=self.BATCH_SIZE)
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset.py", line 192, in image_dataset_from_directory
    dataset = paths_and_labels_to_dataset(
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset.py", line 219, in paths_and_labels_to_dataset
    img_ds = path_ds.map(
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1695, in map
    return MapDataset(self, map_func, preserve_cardinality=True)
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4041, in __init__
    self._map_func = StructuredFunctionWrapper(
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3371, in __init__
    self._function = wrapper_fn.get_concrete_function()
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2938, in get_concrete_function
    graph_function = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2906, in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected
    graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3065, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3364, in wrapper_fn
    ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3299, in _wrapper_helper
    ret = autograph.tf_convert(func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 255, in wrapper
    return converted_call(f, args, kwargs, options=options)
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 532, in converted_call
    return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 339, in _call_unconverted
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset.py", line 220, in <lambda>
    lambda x: path_to_image(x, image_size, num_channels, interpolation))
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset.py", line 228, in path_to_image
    img = io_ops.read_file(path)
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 574, in read_file
    _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
  File "/home/roi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 492, in _apply_op_helper
    raise TypeError("%s expected type of %s." %
TypeError: Input 'filename' of 'ReadFile' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of string.
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63510174/11813527) suggests that it could be the name of your individual .png files that are the issue and renaming them could solve it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have read this answer, however it is not the origin of the error.
I have renamed the images to 001.png 002.png 003.png ...

Comment: From the linked answer, it looks like the number names are an issue. If so, renaming with a string prefix or putting the images in a subdirectory with a string name may resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you again, but after adding a prefix, I still get the same error.
The filenames are image0.png , image1.png ...  
This looks like a tensorflow bug. It is curious that nobody has reported it yet.

Comment: Have the same issue. You didn't figure how to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

One way to fix this I found is to put all your images in another sub-directory inside the directory whose path you are feeding to the `image_dataset_from_directory`.

Taking your example, you would create a new folder, let's call it `new_folder`, inside of `./Folder/` where you would put all your images, such that now the path to all your images is `./Folder/new_folder/`. Then you can call the `image_dataset_from_directory` method with the exact same arguments as you have done in your question:

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  './Folder/',
  label_mode=None,
  batch_size=100
)
```

I found this to work for me so hopefully someone else will also find it helpful!