# How do I load PANDA dataset of kaggle in tensorlfow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, kaggle

I've been trying to load data on [PANDA competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/prostate-cancer-grade-assessment/overview) in tensorflow for training model, but I seem to fail at it. Since the images are in .tiff format, there's much resources online.

Here's what I tried to do

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

and the error message is

```
Input 'filename' of 'ReadFile' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of string.
```

Here's my complete [notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/kwjcndocjn/panda-competition-in-tensorlfow)

Comment: You can check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62378481/ and https://github.com/taki0112/UGATIT/issues/15 of similar issues helps to resolve your issue.

Comment: @Tfer3 Thanks for the reply. Yes, I did follow the above post you're referring to, but it did not solve my problem